# Rails render route path

Tags: routes, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Im still new to Rails and have a hard time understanding how the path system works in Rails.

In my routes.rb i create an alias for signup:

```
match 'signup' => 'user#new'
resource :user, :controller => 'user'
```

The action is there and going to /signup shows the correct action. So far so good.

Now, when i submit my signup form it runs the create action with POST as usual. And here is where im stuck.

If the signup fails, i would like to present the user with the signup form again. One option would be to do a render "new", but that takes the user to /user instead of /signup.

**UserController**

```
class UserController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end


  def create

    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    if @user.save
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render "new"
    end

  end

end
```

Any help appreciated!

**UPDATE - SOLUTION FOUND**

Added 2 match routings for /signup, using the :via option

```
match 'signup' => 'user#new', :as => :signup, :via => 'get'
match 'signup' => 'user#create', :as => :signup, :via => 'post'
```

This way the application knows that when posting to /signup it should run the create action, and when http method is get, it uses the new action.

Controller markup is the same as posted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the "`:as`" to you route like this:

```
match 'signup' => 'user#new', :as => :signup
```

and then do

```
redirect_to signup_url
```

in your controller.

That worked for me. I still don't know why. Maybe someone else has an explanation.

Comment: Hi Hiasinho, thanks for your answer. That will work when redirecting to signup. The case however is that i would like to keep the user object so the form is prefilled. Your answer however got me in the right direction. Ill add the result.