# Can't seem able to show validation errors on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, validationerror

I've been reading rails and ruby tutorials and just got started with my first project. Everything is going well but I'm having a problem showing validation errors for new users. This is my controller code:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to ''
    else
      redirect_to '/signup'
    end
  end
  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :lastname, :nickname, :email, :password)
  end
end
```

And this is my form. I'm omitting all inputs but the nickname one, because I'm testing the validation with it.

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
   <div class='form-group'>
      <%= f.text_field :nickname, :placeholder => "User name", :class => "form-control", :required => true, :minlength => "2", :maxlength => "24" %>
        <div class="text-danger">
          <%= @user.errors[:nickname][0] %>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

I just show the first related error to see if it's working, and avoid any Ifs that would make me doubt if it works or not. The validation on the class is:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books
  has_secure_password
  validates :nickname, uniqueness: true
end
```

When I create a new user by console and try to save it with the same nickname as another it wont save, so the validation works fine. But no error is shown in the view, it just goes back to the signup form and that's all. I'm using ruby 2.2.6 and rails 5.0.1. If I'm missing anything let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of redirect render `new` action template:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to ''
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

When you do redirect you loose `@user` object that contains validation errors. That is why they are not visible in view

Comment: @FranciscoRupto you welcome. If my answer did help you please don't forget to mark it as accepted by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green

Comment: While this works perfectly I have a minor problem. When the validation doesnt pass and it renders #new showing the errors, the url shows "website.com/user". Because the index action doesnt exist, if you reload it can't find the page. How could I change the url shown on the adress bar?

Comment: @FranciscoRupto add one more route to your `routes.rb` file: `match "signup" => "users#create", :via => "post"`. Take a look at this question, for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7533061/rails-render-route-path